# Forward GeoCoding is Working on Simulator but not iPhone

Tags: ios, mkmapview, ios-simulator, geocoding, clgeocoder

So I have a simple application that passes an address as a string to a view which then uses

```
    - (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}
```

and that works great— on the simulator. As soon as I load it on to my phone, the coordinate of the pin I place is no longer at the lat/long of the address, but instead is 0,0.

What's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you running this on in the device and simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```
 - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
    {
        double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
        NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", esc_addr];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];

        if (!err)
        {
            NSLog(@"status = %@",[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"]);
            if ([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"])
            {
                latitude = [[[[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
                longitude = [[[[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
            }
        }

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        center.latitude = latitude;
        center.longitude = longitude;
        return center;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Also I restarted my phone with the current code and it worked for awhile. Perhaps it was a hardware issue as well.